# Unit-SubUnit table query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that serves as a hierarchical component list. Column A shows the Level 1, column B shows Level 2.  Level 2 items in column B will also be listed in the Level 1 column A to then have Level 3 show in column B, and so on.  My first attempt can return only those level 1 items that have a fixed set of lower levels as in the query below, based on number of joins of the table on itself.  I would like to return all that have more than Level 1 whether or not having only a Level 2, or Level 2 & 3, and so on.  I am not well versed on pivot tables, but thinking this may be where the answer lies.

Table: (D under C  under B  under A in a hierarchy)

```
Unit  |  SubUnit
------|--------
    A | B
    B | C
    C | D
    E | F
    F | G
    H | I
```

Desired result

```
L1 | L2 | L3 | L4
 A | B  | C  | D
 E | F  | G
 H | I
```

Current query:

```
SELECT a.[UNIT] AS L1U,a.[SUBUNIT] AS L2U, b.[SUBUNIT] AS L3U,
c.[SUBUNIT] AS L4U
FROM [Table] a JOIN [Table] b ON a.[SUBUNIT] = b.[UNIT] 
JOIN [Table] c ON b.[SUBUNIT] = c.[UNIT]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need `left join`s:

```
SELECT a.[UNIT] AS L1U, a.[SUBUNIT] AS L2U, b.[SUBUNIT] AS L3U,
       c.[SUBUNIT] AS L4U
FROM [Table] a LEFT JOIN
     [Table] b
     ON a.[SUBUNIT] = b.[UNIT] LEFT JOIN
     [Table] c 
     ON b.[SUBUNIT] = c.[UNIT];
```

Otherwise, your results will only contain units that have all four levels.

Comment: That's the solution I needed.  Seems so simple now.  Thank you.